# Can I run wicket websocket in websphere application server?

Tags: websocket, websphere, wicket

I try to implement wicket 7 websocket in websphere application server 8.5.5, but the websocket fails to connect and there is error message

> failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404.

May I know if wicket websocket works in websphere application server?

Comment: I have read the wicket 7 reference guide in https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/7.x/single.html#_native_websockets, and would like to know if wicket websocket only works with tomcat, jetty and jboss wildfly.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `wicket-native-websocket-javax` module then it should work if WebSphere supports JSR-356.

The guide does not mention paid/commercial application servers because we don't have access to them and we don't test on them.

Answer (score 0):

At last, I think websphere application server 8.5.5 full profile, which I am using, does not support JSR 356. Therefore, I cannot use wicket 7 websocket in that server.

Comment: For more detail about websphere application server 8.5.5, please see https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support.html.